# Rewrite variable to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to rewrite an URL with .htaccess.

```
(Actual url) Before: yyy.com/folder/index.php?lang=en
(Their url)  After:  yyy.com/folder/en/index.php

Before: yyy.com/folder/submit.php?lang=da
After:  yyy.com/folder/da/submit.php
```

How do I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Nothing at all. I don't know where to start

Comment: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html.  That took one google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?folder/([a-z]{2})/index\.php$ /folder/index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```